# Prove the following limit equals 0

Tags: calculus

Question: Prove that $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}=0$$ by using the E-D definition.
It suffices to find a $ \delta>0$ such that if $x<\delta \implies \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}< \epsilon $. However you need to use Lambert W function to solve this inequality. Is there any other way to approach this question? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The limit is $0$ or $1$?

Comment: @Cohensiedenberg Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You may  know that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}-1}=1$$

So, you just need proving

$$\lim_{u\to-\infty}u^2e^u=0$$

where $ u=\frac{-1}{x}$.

Comment: Good answer.  But as a point of politeness, please don't ever use the expression "everyone knows that..." because it isn't true and just insults those who haven't learned it yet.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Thanks for your Remark. i edited. is it acceptable now, or no.

Comment: Thank you.  It is certainly fine to say that YOU know it!  So you could say, "you may know that..." or "you might know that..."  I appreciate your courtesy and adaptability.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Thank you very much. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor's Theorem, $e^t=1+t+\frac12t^2+\frac16t^3+o(t^3)\ge \frac16 t^3$, for $t>0$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
0<\frac{e^{-1/x}}{e^{x^2}-1}&\le 6x
\end{align}$$

Hence, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, we see that

$$\left|\frac{e^{-1/x}}{e^{x^2}-1}\right|<\varepsilon$$

whenever $0<x<\delta=\varepsilon/6$.  And we are done!

Comment: For some reason I'm having a hard time tonight seeing what choice(s) of $t$ lead to $6x$ as that nice upper bound. Could you prod me in the right direction?

Comment: Sure.  $$e^{-1/x}=\frac1{e^{1/x}}\le \frac1{\frac16 \,\frac1{x^3}}=6x^3$$

Comment: Ah, thanks, I can see it now.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @Cohensiedenberg Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)